# what is the best way to have an excel formula or VBA code to map to a list

Tags: excel, vba

i have an excel worksheet that has two columns

**Name** and **Town**

There are many rows with the same town (but each row has a distinct name)

So here is an example:

|| Name || Town ||
| Joe | NYC |
| Bill | NYC |
| Tom | NJ |

I now want to have dropdown that is populated by Town and when i click on the dropdown and pick a town it places a concatenated list of names in a cell on the worksheet.

So in this example, the dropdown would show NJ and NYC and if i chose NYC, it would show:

"Joe, Bill" in a cell

Any suggestions on if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part, drop down list - use data validation.  See link

[Create dependent drop down lists containing unique distinct values in excel](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/07/17/create-dependent-drop-down-lists-containing-unique-distinct-values-in-excel/)

Part 2, update a cell based on selection:

Use `Worksheet_Change` event, monitor for changes to cells containing the Towns list values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid VBA for the last part, you can create a helper column to the side of your list.

If your table as shown is in A1:B3, create a helper column in column C as below

For the first row, the helper formula will be =IF(B1=SelectedCity, A1&", ", "")
For the second row, the helper formula will be =C1 & IF(B2=SelectedCity, A2 & ", ", "")
Copy this second row down for all remaining rows.

This formula inductively builds up a comma delimited list of names, contingent on the selected city.

Finally, trim off the extra comma on the end of the comma delimited string with the formula =IF(RIGHT(C3,2)=", ",LEFT(C3, LEN(C3)-2), C3).

This is the string you need.